# Storm door closer that "clicks" open and closed?

Tags: repair, doors

I have a storm door with closers at the top and bottom. The lower one had a unique locking system - when you opened the door far enough it would "click" and stay open. Pushing it a little further unlocked it again.

The cylinder froze open and would no longer close. I went to the local Home Depot, but they don't have this style. Does anyone know what this sort of closer is called? They did have a "touch close" version, which has a button, so alternately should I just use that?

Comment: Can you please post a picture of the closer in question (there are many styles/brands/models)? Also please use the edit function to add any additional information found on the closer (there are usually manufacturer's markings on them).

Comment: Unfortunately it went into the trash over christmas when we were  killer-cleaning the house.